# One of equations error

Tags: equations, page-breaking

I'm writing mathematical paper in Overleaf. I use a lot of equation blocks, but one of them creates additional blank space over and under equation text - in sum 80-90% of the page. Here is the code which I used for this formula. Any other equation works properly. In this case I tried also $ signs - it didn't help. I use packages:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[polish]{babel} % polskie zasady składania dokumentu
\usepackage{polski} % dokument w języku polskim (w tym polskie litery)
\usepackage{amsmath} % do tekstów matematycznych
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{equation*}
\hat{\sigma_k}^2=\frac{1}{N-k-1} \cdot \Sigma_{i=1}^{N-k} w_{ik} \cdot C_{ik}^{\alpha} \cdot (\frac{C_{i,k+1}}{C_{ik}}-\hat{f_k})^2 \end{equation*}
```

[image: site of pdf with the visualization of error]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: you are presumably using `\flushbottom` and you want to use `\raggedbottom` and you have some large non-float  on the next page for some reason. But you have not shown any relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s not really sufficient information to identify precisely what’s going wrong here, but the most likely cause is that there is something on page 15 that’s causing LaTeX to be unable to find a good page break and is forcing it to stretch out the available stretching space (which is the above and display skips). I wouldn't be surprised if the vertical spacing on page 13 is also a bit large to prevent breaking the paragraph at the top of page 14 before the last line.

The equation itself is not the problem and neither are the packages being loaded.

Comment: It helped, thank you!